# Grails throws NonUniqueObjectException when findWhere called

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, grails-orm

I am building a grails application with domain classes whose id generator is assigned (that is, they do not auto-generate).  Assume I have a domain class Parent with `static hasMany = [children: Child]` and domain class Child.

I am trying to locate an instance of Parent using `Parent.findWhere(propertyMap)`, but am getting a **NonUniqueObjectException** indicating that there is already a Child instance associated with this session having id 0.  My propertyMap does not contain an entry for id.

Now, I am used to getting this error any time I try to save two instances of one class in a session without setting their ids.  Because ids are not auto-generated, they default to zero, which allows the first to be saved, and the second throws an error, as the id is a duplicate of the first.  What is surprising me here is that I am trying to find an instance, not save one... Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior and how I can get around it while still searching using my property map?

Comment: Try "findAllWhere" and see what it returns.

Comment: Same.  I have a feeling `findAllWhere` and `findWhere` either depend on one another or have identical implementations with the exception of the number of results returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a groovy syntactical sugar problem.  I was calling findWhere like

```
Parent.findWhere([ firstProperty: "firstValue", secondProperty: "SecondValue" ])
```

but apparently I should be using

```
Parent.findWhere( firstProperty: "firstValue", secondProperty: "SecondValue" )
```

(note the lack of square brackets).  I don't know why this made a difference, but findWhere works as expected now.  Extra points to anyone who might know why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Hibernate has a strong constraint that you can't have 2 objects representing the same id in the session, as you know. The thing that maybe you didn't notice is that no matter if it's in a `save()` operation or update or even a dynamic query: if there are 2 objects with same id in the same Hibernate Session, Hibernate will raise an exception like that one. Be sure that there is another object just like that one in your session.

[Here](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/) it says:

> If you use GORM to retrieve a domain instance in any way, for example
>   via the get() method or any type of query, then the object is
>   automatically associated with the session.

Probably there is a Child object in session referencing a Parent one (that does not have an id yet). I don't see other elegant way out of this except give your parent objects ids before they go to the session or avoid saving a Child referencing a Parent to the session. Other way would be to use `evict()` on your objects like: `session.evict(object)`. But that's not a nice thing to do.

Cheers!

Comment: The thing is, findWnere shouldn't be creating an object at all, it should be finding an object that already exists.  How could this lead to an id collision if no new ids are created?